# How to execute only 1 job build at a time in Jenkins

Tags: jenkins

I have only 1 job in Jenkins. This job gets build multiple number of times. I want Jenkins to execute only 1 build at a time and keep remaining builds (to be executed next) in the build queue. **I have changed the no. of build executors available from 2 to 1, still some part of the next build gets executed along with the current build**. How to achieve this?

Comment: You need to disable options for concurrent builds.

Comment: @SiddharthKaul disabling concurrency build is preventing me from scheduling more builds unless currently executing build is completed. Can you suggest something?

Comment: That is not the behaviour for that. Disabling concurrent builds makes sure only 1 build run at a time. The other requests in your case will be put in the build queue. Not sure if you are using the Jenkins UI but even in case of UI the request for other builds can be scheduled.

Answer (score 0):

So I searched and learnt how Jenkins actually works, even if your build is in build queue and is waiting for an executor, it will still have building state as TRUE. So eventually only one build will be executed at a time but all those other builds in the queue will also be in building phase waiting for an executor.